# Can we define order of weaving when using AspectJ load time weaving?

Tags: aop, aspectj, aspect

I have two aspects and I would want to know that if there is a way I can perform load time weaving for all of them but in a certain order.

Right now, the only way I can think of is doing the same via run-time/execution time weaving using spring proxies or something.

Edit below:

I tried to add a new aspect with @DeclarePrecendence and weave that as well in my aop.xml but that does not seem to work.

```
@Aspect
```

@DeclarePrecedence("aspect1, aspect2")
public class AspectOrdering {

```
/**
 * Default constructor to allow instantiation by the AspectJ Weaver (has to be no-args).
 */
public AspectOrdering() {
    // no instantiation done by constructor as arguments cannot be passed
}
```

}

Update:
It works. I think the server where I was testing was not picking up the updated aop.xml earlier.

Comment: What have you tried already? Post some code so people have something to work off.

Comment: Edited the question with what I have tried.

Comment: @DeclarePrecedence works

Comment: As your problems was actually just dependent on your server, I suggest you delete this question because it does not add any value to anyone reading it. Thank you.